# django email username and password

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, webfaction

I'm implementing a contact form for one of my sites. One thing I'm not sure I understand completely is why you need `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`.

The user would only need to provide his/her email address, so what is the `EMAIL_HOST_USER` referring to then and why would I need to specify an email and password?

EDIT:
I'm using webfaction as my mail server

Comment: That's the username and password to connect to your outgoing mail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set **EMAIL_HOST** and **EMAIL_PORT** just for sending emails to your user.

> Mail is sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_PORT settings. The EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD settings, if set, are used to authenticate to the SMTP server, and the EMAIL_USE_TLS and EMAIL_USE_SSL settings control whether a secure connection is used.